# Object doesn't support property or method 'format' IE7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am receiving an error message "Object doesn't support property or method 'format'" when running the following code in IE 7/8 Browser and Document Mode. I am using Knob - jQuery Plugin.

```
// Dial logic
var Dial = function (c, opt) {

    var v = null
        ,ctx = c[0].getContext("2d")
        ,PI2 = 2 * Math.PI
        ,mx ,my ,x ,y
        ,self = this;

    this.onChange = function () {};
    this.onCancel = function () {};
    this.onRelease = function () {};

    this.val = function (nv) {
        if (null != nv) {
            opt.stopper && (nv = Math.max(Math.min(nv, opt.max), opt.min));
            v = nv;
            this.onChange(nv);
            this.draw(nv);
        } else {
            var b, a;
            b = a = Math.atan2(mx - x, -(my - y - opt.width / 2)) - opt.angleOffset;
            (a < 0) && (b = a + PI2);
            nv = Math.round(b * (opt.max - opt.min) / PI2) + opt.min;
            return (nv > opt.max) ? opt.max : nv;
        }
    };
```

Comment: You need more context within the rest of your code for this to make sense.

Comment: Which of the assignments throws that error (or is it a variable declaration)? Test them separately. Also, are you sure the error stems from this line - there is no `format` at all?

Comment: No need to test anything, the variable names and the getContext makes it pretty clear that is something that has something to do with a canvas. Since there is no canvas support in IE7/8, which would have taken five seconds to figure out with a Google search, it really does'nt matter much exactly where the error is.

Answer (score 2):

That's simply that there is no canvas in IE before IE9. You can't do anything besides recommending to your users an upgrade.

See [the compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas).

HTML5 makes a lot of new applications possible. People wanting to use them can't keep their old browser.

Comment: You can't do anything besides recommend an upgrade? What about libraries that simulate it...like excanvas?

Comment: @Ian Those libraries don't work fast enough as soon as you do something a little more complex than drawing a square and they're generally painful to maintain. In my opinion they're bringing us back to the time where we had to make different codes for IE and Netscape/Firefox...

Answer (score 1):

You can add canvas support for IE7/IE8 with [explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/).